# Intel video black patches 16.04

Tags: drivers, video

I'm new to Ubuntu and have just installed 16.04 on my laptop.  The desktop and most applications display perfectly but I have problems with mp4 videos.  VLC gives me audio but a black window.  Videos (the built-in player) shows the picture but with large black rectangles and triangles flickering on and off covering the top half of the screen.  It's not a bad file; I've tried several mp4s from different sources which play OK elsewhere.  YouTube HTML5 videos at the same resolution play perfectly in Firefox.  I installed the 0 AD game - the intro screen flickers in a similar way, though not as badly (smaller shapes, sky blue rather than black), so I don't think we can blame my installation of VLC or Videos.

`lspci -k` says I have a

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: 
        Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family 
        Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09).
```

I'm happy to add further info if you tell me what's needed.

Any suggestions please?  I'm guessing it's a driver issue but not sure what to update.  Intel's site has drivers for 15.xx which may not be appropriate.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Go into the VLC preferences > Video, and try one of the other "Output" options (I'd recommend trying on of the "XCB" options first, and maybe the experimental OpenGL one), restart VLC, and try playing the video again. If still no success, you can try unchecking "Accelerated output / overlay".

Comment: Thank you Jonas.  Selecting VLC X11 video output (XCB) gives me a perfect picture. I think there's something else wrong, as I get the artifacts in 0 AD, but your suggestion answers my question and makes a big improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [**SMPlayer**](http://smplayer.sourceforge.net), the biggest difference between VLC and Smplayer is that smplayer is a front-end for the award-winning playback engine [MPlayer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPlayer) which is one of the best free-open-source players in the world. (*according to the [smplayer page](http://smplayer.sourceforge.net/)*)

Smplayer it has also  built-in codecs and you can also make customization to the **toolbars** and it has also **themes** and many other thing like VLC does and is also under GPL.

*Installing the latest version please see: http://smplayer.sourceforge.net/en/downloads*

Comment: Thank you, SMPlayer also works for me, so that's another good solution.  As a bonus, my other test case of 0 AD stopped glitching, so I may have accidentally updated a driver that it uses too.